# Finding a way to download course materials to android mobile

Tags: java, android, google-classroom

Is there any way to download google drive file to custom location? I am using this code to get the file,

```
courses.get(0).getCourseMaterialSets().get(0).getMaterials().get(0).getDriveFile()
```

This function is returning File type output. How to save it locally?

Or is there any way to download google drive files using classroom API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this using Classroom API. To download files from Google Drive, check the download files tutorial using [Android API for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads).

> **Downloading a file**
>
> Preferred method: using alt=media
>
> To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the
>   file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
> ```
>
> Authorization: Bearer
>   ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs Downloading the file
>   requires the user to have at least read access. Additionally, your app
>   must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content.
>   For example, an app using the drive.readonly.metadata scope would not
>   be authorized to download the file contents. Users with edit
>   permission may restrict downloading by read-only users by setting the
>   restricted label to true.

Here's a snippet from the guide:

```
/**
   * Download a file's content.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param file Drive File instance.
   * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
   *         {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
      try {
        // uses alt=media query parameter to request content
        return service.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAsInputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }
```